# how to implement if in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, href, src

The javascript below extracts `www.google.com` from `http://mysite.com?url=www.google.com`
and writes it as an `<a>` `href` link

```
<script> 
var urll = (window.location.search.match(/[?&;]url=([^&;]+)/) || [])[1]; 
document.write('<a href="http://'+urll+'">url</a>'); 
</script>
```

The problem with it is that when it extracts the url the `<a>` `href` value it becomes  `http://mysite.com/www.google.com` so the `if` should state if the original url `http://mysite.com?url=www.google.com` doesn't have `http://` infront of `?url=` then add it after the  `href` value to form `<a href="http://www.google.com">url</a>`

In a comment for a previous question someone gave me this

```
if (link.substr(0, 7) !== 'http://') { link = 'http://' + link; }
```

but I really don't have a clue on how to implement it because I have never used an `if` in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from anything else you're making yourself suspectible to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

Assume for a moment that the `url` parameter (which an external site can *easily* spoof by providing a link to your site) contains the string `"><b>BOLD!</b><div class="`. Suddenly your page would display some bold text, even 'though you never used a `<b>` tag in your site. And that's the most harmless example possible, because the attacker can equally well introduce arbitrary JavaScript into your page (including JS that steals the users cookie!).

Moral of the story: **never** blindly trust user input, and don't simply convert it to HTML.

To avoid these kinds of attacks ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a very similar attack against server-side code that builds SQL statements) do these two things:

1. validate the input to ensure that it's exactly what you expect and don't accept it if it doesn't. In your case that would mean that you'd want to make sure that the `url` parameter actually represents a valid URL.
2. Use user data only in "safe" ways that don't introduce the possibility of "re-interpretation" of the input. In your case it means that you must not build your HTML using string concatenation like this. Intead use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) to create your `a` element, set its `href` attribute to the desired value (sanitized as stated above) and then add the newly created `a` element in your DOM at the appropriate position.

Comment: @Yusaf: 1.) **validate** the input to ensure that it's **exactly** what you expect (i.e. only accept it if it's a correct URL) and 2.) don't use string concatenation like this, instead [create an `a` element in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement), set its `href` attribute directly and then insert that element at the appropriate place in the DOM.

Comment: looks like i need to go back to the drawing board :(. thankyou. I only know HTML and CSS and little javascript as you can tell..

Comment: @Yusaf: building secure web applications is a hard, but very necessary skill. If you take your time to learn it, you **will** be rewarded and have skills that (unfortunately) too many people *don't* have.

Comment: btw are you talking about having the link as something like this http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fperishablepress taken from http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/11/30/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/

Comment: `document.write(encodeURIComponent(urll));` and would this help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript.  "if" is the most basic element of any programming language, if you don't understand that you'll really need to run through a bunch of basics.

Comment: The last thing anybody needs is a link to w3schools.

Comment: Preferably, link to the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Comment: All fair.  "Quick and dirty" was my goal.